# Do metametaphysics help in elucidating the problems in metaphysics?

Tags: metaphysics, metaphilosophy

I have found a couple of books relating to metametaphysics, and it surprises me that this branch of philosophy exists.

Before I plunge myself down a new rabbit hole, I would appreciate help in putting this field in perspective, as to whether it helps with metaphysics the same way metaphysics (ideally) helps with physics and science in general.

Comment: Metaphysics is the elephant in the room of sciences. Any knowledge has a necessary empirical and a metaphysical component. Being the metaphysical one eminently subjective, it is difficult to address as such. So, evidently it is a matter of concern for the production of scientific knowledge. Meta-metaphysics, AFAIK, tries to address such kind of issues if metaphysics.

Comment: What is Metametaphysics?  It attempts to answer questions such as: what is the proper subject matter of metaphysics? Thus, it is hard to believe that is something basically different from metaphysics itself.

Comment: Metaphysics does not relate to physics the same way metametaphysics relates to metaphysics, metamathematics to mathematics or metalogic to logic. If X studies X-items then "meta-X" usually means "studies of studies of X-items". But "metaphysics" label is an accident of history, "meta" means "after" in Greek, and Aristotle's unnamed books that became that were placed after his Physics by the editors. However, metametaphysics means, as usual, studies of metaphysical studies. Unless you have first order experience with a variety of the latter already you will not benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

Mario Bunge, who calls himself an exact philosopher, once wrote down a formula for philosophy:

> P^2 = P

Meaning the philosophy of philosophy is philosophy. Likewise, I would suggest he would say the metaphysics of metaphysics is metaphysics.

Comment: I call foul there for pulling at my heart strings citing Bunge.

Comment: "**P^2 = P**" Should be P(P) ⊂ P, which makes better sense.